# Retrieving, Updating , deleting etc on attachments corresponding a row in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-drive-api

I am able to perform CRUD specific operations through Google Drive Spreadsheet API on Google Spreadsheets stored in Google Drive.

Each row of Google spreadsheet contains references of few attachments files and exists in Google drive inside a folder. Now I need to access the attachments corresponding to each row of Google spreadsheets in a Google Drive. And I don't want to make the files Public due to security reason.

How can I access the attachment files through code specific to Google App Engine? I am using GAE SDK.

I tried Google Drive API for the same , but din't work. Please suggest.

Comment: What information do you have for each row of the spreadsheet? Is it file id? file & folder name?

Comment: We have info about file and folder. The spreadsheet file and attachments are inside a folder, so how to get file id basically.